# Oracle script for Round number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to this site and oracle sqlplus in general. I need some help, I need to write a script that will round a number in 50 to the next highest number. Foe example:

```
If between 1100 to 1149.99   ----> The output would be  1100 
If between 1100 to 1189.99   ----> The output would be  1150
```

Could you please help me for this scrip.

Thanks

Comment: You have typos on your second line - should say between 1150 to 1199.99 I believe.

Comment: don't forget to come back and pick the right answer or let us know what is missing to solve this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are unclear about what you really want (next highest or next lowest):

```
mynum := Ceil(mynum / 50) * 50;
mynum := Floor(mynum / 50) * 50;
```

Comment: I think FLOOR is what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
select round(chrg/50)*50 from chrg